# Fortran Call Errors

Tags: fortran

In my Fortran code, I have the commands:

```
CALL EXPECTATION(X, 0.5D0*SIGMAZ, Z_EXPECTATION)
WRITE(1,*) T, Z_EXPECTATION

CALL EXPECTATION(X, 0.5D0*SIGMAY, Y_EXPECTATION)
WRITE(4,*) T, Y_EXPECTATION
```

for which I get the errors:

```
Error: Symbol ‘sigmay’ at (1) has no IMPLICIT type

Error: Symbol ‘sigmaz’ at (1) has no IMPLICIT type
```

But I get no error for a similar command:

```
CALL EXPECTATION(X, 0.5D0*SIGMAX, X_EXPECTATION)
WRITE(3,*) T, X_EXPECTATION
```

What could be the issue? I am calling the variables from the same subroutine and I have defined them to be

```
COMPLEX*16, DIMENSION(2,2) :: SIGMAX, SIGMAY SIGMAZ
```

Comment: Please show a more complete (but small) example which reproduces the error.  See [mcve].

Comment: Note your declaration appears to be missing a comma, is this just a typo here or in the source code as well?

Comment: And to follow d_1999's comment: are you using fixed-form source code?  There, spaces in this declaration are ignored (so you'll have a variable called `sigmaysigmaz`).

Comment: If a comment helps you solve your problem it would be useful for others if you can provide a comment/question update to note this. That way future people will know what the solution was.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a comma in the declaration between `SIGMAY` and `SIGMAZ`. <del>Since Fortran doesn't care about whitespaces, it created only two complex variables: `SIGMAX` and `SIGMAYSIGMAZ`.</del>

Just add the comma and your code should compile fine.

Comment: I think "Fortran doesn't care about whitespaces" isn't accurate, it's true for fixed-form but not free-form. See for example [this](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/fortran/2103/modern-alternatives-to-historic-features/11457/fixed-source-form#t=201608171315193077528) documentation topic/example.

Comment: Interesting. I should have tested first. I still think that the missing comma is the bug, but then the compiler should have complained with the declaration...

Comment: The missing comma is certainly important.  In free-form source there will be a syntax problem, but in fixed-form there's no declaration at all: it's a comment line.  Either way, the question is not an accurate representation of the underlying issue.